# Masking Output Cells with < 2 Counted

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to find a way to obscure or mask cells from outputs that contain less than a certain threshold of respondents in a CrossTable. I need the outputs to be displayed, but with a placeholder or NA in the cell.

I can filter the rows that would lead to a cell that would not have the correct number of respondents, but this leaves the cell with 0. This makes a difference in interpreting the output, as for example, 6 Men and less than 5 women in construction is different than 6 men and 0 women in construction.

```
library(dplyr)
library(descr)
# Test Unique Combinations <2, Fake data 

Hide <- data.frame(Gend = c("Pref No Resp", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male",
                            "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female"),
                   Job = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1),
                  Dayson = c(0, 2, 3, 44, 55, 12, 12, 8, 10, 1, 2))

# Complete Output
CrossTable(Hide$Gend, Hide$Job, chisq = FALSE, prop.t = FALSE, prop.c = FALSE, prop.chisq = FALSE)

# If I Filter - 
Hide2 <- Hide %>% group_by(Gend, Job) %>% filter(n()>1)

CrossTable(Hide2$Gend, Hide2$Job, chisq = FALSE, prop.t = FALSE, prop.c = FALSE, prop.chisq = FALSE)
```

Effectively, I'm looking for the results in the Complete Output code, but with the bottom row with NA, -99, or some other value that would hide the result without producing 0, yet still maintaining the rows and columns.

[image: Output, But Needing X in Counts for Pref No Resp]

For Example, the two values (1 and 0) in the above "Pref No Resp" line would be X or NA

I have been using the CrossTable from descr package, but am open to others. I need as automated as possible, as the script will be utilizing different groups of data with a large number of outputs.

Thanks all!

Comment: Could you show current and expected output?

Comment: @NelsonGon Thanks! I've added the current and an explanation of expected. Hope this helps!